# Insert a variable in the middle of the string but keep the single quotes (C#)

Tags: c#, string

How to insert a variable to a piece of string with keeping single quotes as a part of the string.

CODE:

```
var textMessage = "myText"; //local variable storing text to be injected to string
```

this is what I have tried but it did't work:

```
"//div[contains(@id,'msgError') and contains(text(),'+textMessage+')]" //string where textMessage should be insterted
```

OUTPUT should be like this:

```
"//div[contains(@id,'msgError') and contains(text(),'myText')]" //Output
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
string.Format("//div[contains(@id,'msgError') and contains(text(),'{0}')]", textMessage)
```

you can specify more parameters to put in string.

Answer (score 2):

```
"//div[contains(@id,'msgError') and contains(text(),'+textMessage+')]"
```

That's a single string literal in C# syntax, everything except special characters will be in the string as is. In order for `textMessage` to evaluate to its value, you have to add it as an expression:

```
"//div[contains(@id,'msgError') and contains(text(),'" + textMessage + "')]"
```

Now the result will be the concatenation of the first string literal, plus `textMessage` variable's value, plus the last string literal.

As a *sidenote*, concatenating strings like this is usually frowned upon, it's better to use [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You're close.  The textMessage has to be outside the string:

```
"//div[contains(@id,'msgError') and contains(text(),'" + textMessage + "')]"
```

In your solution, textMessage and the two plus characters are just part of the literal string.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `string.Format(string, object...)` solutions already mentioned I just want to point out that in C# 6.0 you can use the new string interpolation feature:

```
const string queenType = "lizard";
var message = $"I am the {queenType} queen!";
```

It works similarly to `string.Format(string, object...)`, but I think it's a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

For basic string templating in C#, `string.Format` is your friend.

```
var textMessage = "myText"; 
var template = "//div[contains(@id,'msgError') and contains(text(),'{0}')]";
var output = string.Format(template, textMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

i whould use the string.Format where you can use placeholders "{x}" in the string. these placeholders you can add as meny as you need to the string provided that you swift the x with the matching index in the paramiters after. 
in your example

```
war textmessage = "myText";
string.Format("This is formated to end with {0}",textmessage);
```

this whould write This is formated to end with myText.

you can build on this by adding more parameters.

```
var name1 = "Emil";
var name2 = "Rachel"; 
string.Format("{1} and {0} are friends",name1,name2);
```

the index as you se does not have to be 0 1 2 but can be shifted around to suit your needs.

hope this helps :)